# What's the difference between Python for and Tensorflow tf.while_loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do something to a tensor. Such as repeat it at a dimension.

I can implement it using either `Python for` loop or `tf.while_loop`. What's the difference between them?

Let's say that I'd loop it 5 times. Will `Python for` affect back propagation? Will `Python for` make back propagation 5 times?

Comment: You can use `tf.tile()` to repeat a tensor instead of `Python for` and `tf.while_loop`. Generally speaking, it is more appropriate to use `tf.while_loop` in tensorflow than `Python for` .

Comment: @giser_yugang Thank you for your answer. The repeat thing is just an example. I'm glad if you cloud tell me more about their differences. And what will they affect back propagation? Will it back propagate several times?